# Number of generators of the fundamental group of a Riemannian manifold with Ricci curvature bounded below

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology

Is there a constant $C(n,D)$ such that for any closed Riemannian manifold $M$ with $Ric \ge -(n - 1)$ and $\mathrm{diam} \le D$, the fundamental group $\pi_1(M)$ is generated by at most $C(n,D)$ elements? This statement holds when $\sec \ge -1$.

Comment: It might follow from Kapovitch--Wilking paper, but better ask them directly. (BTW you could formulate the question better).

Comment: Is there a constant $C(n,D)$ so that for any compact manifold $M$ with  ...

Comment: I edited the question so as to make it clearer. I hope I did not mess up any of the hypotheses. To be safe, I also added the assumption that the manifold is closed. Feel free to revert or change my edits.

Comment: Anton is right. It is Theorem 3 in Kapovitch-Wilking's paper.